# PHP: access to a protected variable impossible

Tags: php, oop

I'm writing for exercise this 2 classes:

```
abstract class SocialNetworks
{
    abstract protected function getFacebookGraph();

} // class SocialNetworks

class GetSocialNetworks extends SocialNetworks
{
    protected $fbData;
    public function setFacebookData($facebookData) {
        $this->fbData = $facebookData;
        $this->getFacebookGraph($this->fbData);
    }
    protected function getFacebookGraph() {
        print_r($this->fbData);
    }
}
```

(`$facebookData` is an array).

In this mode this class prints correctly the array that i passed.

But i cannot access in any mode "directly" to `$fbData` but only with `$this->fbData`. Otherwise I get

```
Undefined variable: fbData
```

Is it normal or is there a method to use directly `$fbData`

I repeat... these are my first exercises in OOP, so I need to learn more and more.

Comment: It is normal, don't worry ..

Comment: `$this->fbData` is the syntax when you are referring to object properties. `$fbData` is when referring to free variables. This is [explained in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: After reading Jon's link about properties, read up on visibility http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the scope:

`$this->variable` for use inside of object

`self::$variable` for use inside of static class

`parent::$variable` for the use inside of a child object to access father class

`$variable` for use inside of local scope

Class members are not local, they are relative super.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages you can access class members without "this". Thats not the case with php. Here you allways have to use "$this".